# about printing a 2D array in php

Tags: php

I'd like to ask why when i echo a specific cell like this in PHP:

```
echo "$array[0][0]";
```

I get something like: Array[0]
and when I echo it like this:

```
echo $array[0][0];
```

I take the value.
Just curious, can't understand why. :/

Comment: it should be echo "{$array[0][0]}";

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I tried a 1D array also, and it worked with echo "$array[0]"; .
Can't understand why.

Answer (score 2):

The *simple* string interpolation syntax allows one level of arrays to be interpreted:

```
"foo $array[0] bar"
```

This evaluates the value of variables inside of a string literal. It's a convenience feature to save you from typing lots of concatenation operators (`'foo ' . $array[0] . ' bar'`).

There's also the *complex* string interpolation syntax, which allows nested expressions:

```
"foo {$array[0][0]} bar"
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.

On the other hand:

```
echo $array[0][0];
```

This accesses the array value directly as it's meant to be accessed, without the specific restrictions of string interpolation rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can put variables in strings if you use `"`, but php cannot guess if you mean `$array[0]` and then the string `[0]`, or the actual variable `$array[0][0]`. It guessed the first.

If you want to do this in a string, add `{` to show what is the variable.

```
echo "{$array[0][0]}"
```